# Cannot solve java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, indexoutofboundsexception

In **Edit_WorkDetails**, it has a `listView` used to populate the data retrieved from `SQLite`.

```
     ListView listViewUpdate;
     CustomBaseAdapter obj;
     private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
     Long ID, iD;
     ArrayList<DetailsBean> results = new ArrayList<DetailsBean>();

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View edit_details = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_work_details, container, false);
            dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
            sqlcon = new WorkDetailsAPI(getContext());
            listViewUpdate = (ListView) edit_details.findViewById(R.id.listViewEdit);
            obj = new CustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(), results, listViewUpdate);
            listViewUpdate.setAdapter(obj);
            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                ID = bundle.getLong("ID"); // receive ID from other activity, Assume is ID=1
                BuildEditDetails(ID);
            }

     public void BuildEditDetails(long ID) {
            final long id = ID;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), id + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            sqlcon.open();
            Cursor cursor = sqlcon.readData(id);

            String[] columns = new String[]{MyDatabaseHelper.Project, MyDatabaseHelper.WorkDescription};

            int[] to = new int[]
                    {
                         R.id.Project, R.id.Description     };
            dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.retrieve_details, cursor, columns, to, 0);

            listViewUpdate.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        }
```

When the list is clicked,it will go to **Edit_Details** for edit.

```
  listViewUpdate.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition = position;
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                iD = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), iD + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Details.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID", iD);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        });
```

`iD` represent the id in listView and value `2` is displayed.

**Edit_Details**

All the data which belong to iD (2) will be displayed on **Edit_Details**. When the save `button` is clicked, updated value will be saved to `SQLite` and return to **Edit_WorkDetails** `listView`.

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     // if save button clicked
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                project1=Project2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                description=Description.getText().toString();
                sqlcon.open();
                sqlcon.Update(ID, project1, description);  // update the latest value in SQLite
                returnIntent.putExtra("project1", project1);
                returnIntent.putExtra("description", description);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

And this is the `OnActivityResult` for **Edit_WorkDetails**

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                ReceiveProject = data.getStringExtra("Project");
                ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("Description");

                if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                    if (obj != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "S", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } else {
                    if (obj != null)  // obj is CustomBaseAdapter object
                        obj.changeItem(mClickedPosition, ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**CustomBaseAdapter**

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   // for ListView


    private static ArrayList<DetailsBean> searchArrayList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ListView listview;


    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DetailsBean> results,ListView listview) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        this.listview=listview;
         mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public void changeItem(int m,String P,String D)
    {
       DetailsBean obj = new DetailsBean();
        obj.setProject("   "+P);
        obj.setDescription("  "+" Work Description : " + " "+D);
        searchArrayList.set(m,obj);
        this. notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

**DetailsBean**

```
private String project="";
 private String description="";

public class DetailsBean {

  public void setProject(String project){
            this.project=project;
        }

        public String getProject()
        {
            return project;
        }


public void setDescription(String description){
            this.description=description;
        }

        public String getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

    }
```

When save button in Edit_Details is clicked, app crashed.

**LogCat Error**

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:481)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.Adapter.CustomBaseAdapter.changeItem(CustomBaseAdapter.java:47)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.Edit_WorkDetails.onActivityResult(Edit_WorkDetails.java:125)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:156)
```

Can someone help me?

These two codes have error

```
 obj.changeItem(mClickedPosition, ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription);
```

and

```
searchArrayList.set(m,obj);
```

Comment: "Hours"?  The problem is right here: com.example.project.myapplication.Adapter.CustomBaseAdapter.changeItem(CustomBaseAdapter.java:47).  A spin through a debugger will solve this in half an hour, tops.  That's if you get coffee.

Comment: I tried to write a good question here. Any helps would be greatly appreciated . :)

Comment: Don't use static in adapter, enable debug mode and check each and every line of code so that you can find where is gap. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this member class in your custom adapter should be static:

```
static ArrayList<DetailsBean> searchArrayList;
```

"static" means it's associated with the class, not instances.  When you set it in the constructor, that's true for every instance.

This is a bad idea, too:

```
searchArrayList = results;
```

You should make a copy so that reference stays private:

```
this.searchArrayList = new ArrayList<DetailsBean>(results);
```

This is the line with the problem:

```
searchArrayList.set(m,obj);
```

You pass in `m=1`, but that `List` has been initialized so that it's empty.

```
ArrayList<DetailsBean> results = new ArrayList<DetailsBean>();
```

That's the List you pass to the constructor when you create the `CustomBaseAdapter`.  I don't see where you change it.  Are those results from the SQL database?  Perhaps your query returns no results, but you assume that it does.

What is a `DetailsBean`?  That's two generic names combined to provide no insight whatsoever as to what this object is.  I'd rethink that.  It looks like you want project name and description inside that object.  Why not call it `Project`?  That's what it is.

Are those private variables supposed to be inside your `DetailsBean`?  If not, who owns them?  That looks wrong, too.  Does this even compile?

Your code doesn't follow Java coding standards.  Your naming is inconsistent and confusing.  Variable names should start with a lower case letter; classes start with upper case letter.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Should I remove the static ?

Comment: I think so.  You should also use a debugger and see where your assumptions are not matching the true behavior of the code.

Comment: I had removed the `private static` and change `searchArrayList = results;` to `this.searchArrayList = new ArrayList<DetailsBean>(results);`, but still getting the same error

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=196609, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.project.myapplication/com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.ActivityB}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

Comment: Use a debugger.  Is this all the code I'd need to compile and run this?  Nevermind - SQLite and a database mean it's too much work for me.  Learn how to use an IDE and a debugger.

Comment: Who says I'm mad?   Stop projecting your insecurities.